# How can I extract just text from the html

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

I have a requirement to extract all the text that is present in the `<body>` of the html. Sample Html input :-

```
<html>
    <title>title</title>
    <body>
           <h1> This is a big title.</h1>
           How are doing you?
           <h3> I am fine </h3>
           <img src="abc.jpg"/>
    </body>
</html>
```

The output should be :-

```
This is a big title. How are doing you? I am fine
```

I want to use only HtmlAgility for this purpose. No regular expressions please.

I know how to load HtmlDocument and then using xquery like '//body' we can get body contents. But how do I strip the html as I have shown in output?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/846994/how-to-use-html-agility-pack) for some HTML Agility Pack links. I would guess you have to call something like `InnerText` property on the `HtmlNode`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the body's `InnerText`:

```
string html = @"
<html>
    <title>title</title>
    <body>
           <h1> This is a big title.</h1>
           How are doing you?
           <h3> I am fine </h3>
           <img src=""abc.jpg""/>
    </body>
</html>";

HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(html);
string text = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//body").InnerText;
```

Next, you may want to collapse spaces and new lines:

```
text = Regex.Replace(text, @"\s+", " ").Trim();
```

Note, however, that while it is working in this case, markup such as `hello<br>world` or `hello<i>world</i>` will be converted by `InnerText` to `helloworld` - removing the tags. It is difficult to solve that issue, as display is ofter determined by the CSS, not just by the markup.

Comment: Note htat "/html/body" for xpath is much faster.

Comment: It's giving error. Unable to find namespace for HtmlDocument .

Comment: @Er.ShaileshS.Bankar - Do you have the [Html Agility Pack](https://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) library?

Comment: No, do I have to add it firts?

Answer (score 3):

How about using the XPath expression `'//body//text()'` to select all text nodes?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [NUglify](https://github.com/xoofx/NUglify) that supports text extraction from HTML:

```
var result = Uglify.HtmlToText("<div>  <p>This is <em>   a text    </em></p>   </div>");
Console.WriteLine(result.Code);   // prints: This is a text
```

As it is using a HTML5 custom parser, it should be quite robust (specially if the document doesn't contain any errors) and is a very fast (no regexp involved but a pure recursive descent parser, faster than HtmlAgilityPack and more GC friendly)

Answer (score 1):

Normally for parsing html I would recommend a HTML parser, however since you want to remove all html tags a simple regex should work.