# How to read text present in html node in c#?

Tags: c#, html, regex, asp.net-mvc

I want to read data(string) present in between body tag like below -

```
<body> Text to read </body>
```

How can I do it without using HtmlAgilityPack? Please help. Thank you.

Comment: @Ehsan Sajjad, Isn't there any other way to do that?

Comment: What about parsing the text as XML?

Comment: @hbulens , I've complete file of html including inline css, script tags etc. So it'll be a bit difficult to do that.

Comment: u can use the body's InnerText

Comment: @VinothRaj , please provide possible solution.

Comment: **See this Link:** **Link** - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5847659/how-can-i-extract-just-text-from-the-html

Comment: What have you already tried? Be aware that you've given a very simple question so far with minimal detail and no indication of what you've attempted - at this stage, a simple substring function would be a full and complete answer to your question, yet be absolutely useless.

Comment: @AdrianWragg , I don't want to use string function. And I've got solution.

Comment: @Er.ShaileshS.Bankar My point was that your question was very vague, and gave no indication of how complex the HTML could be.

Comment: @EhsanSajjad - what a pointless response. Flagged as non-constructive.

Comment: Sorry about that,  i missed that it's asp.net mvc tagged

Comment: @AdrianWragg , I don't think that you have something to do with the html complexity. I think it's pointless to ask about it as Complexity of html is not a factor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got solution and without using HtmlAgilityPack and string function.I've used `Regex`. It's as follows-

```
        string html = "<body>Text to read </body>";

        RegexOptions options = RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Singleline;
        Regex regx = new Regex("<body>(?<theBody>.*)</body>", options);

        Match match = regx.Match(html);

        if (match.Success)
        {
            string theBody = match.Groups["theBody"].Value;
            //Here I'm getting all the data present in body tag              

        }
```